# Function reads ALL your Facebook groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am listing the groups via api 2.5 using the following function:

```
function getMyGroups() {
        FB.api('/me/groups', function(response) {
            var groupList = document.getElementById('groups');
            response.data.forEach(function(group) {
                console.log(group);
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.value = group.id;
                opt.innerHTML = group.name;
                groupList.appendChild(opt);
            });
        }, {
            scope: 'user_managed_groups,publish_actions'
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly, but only returns the groups created by me. there is some calls to make and return all groups that I participate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `user_groups` permission is gone and you can only access groups you manage since v2.4 of the Graph API.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: no, there is no other way. what would you do with the list anyway, if you don´t manage the groups? facebook removed access mostly because people tried so spam groups.